# Apache flume Regex Extractor Interceptor

Tags: hadoop, flume, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to append the header using Regex Extractor Interceptor but it is not working.
I am not sure where I am going wrong. Below is my config file content :

```
agent.channels = CH
agent.channels.CH.type = memory
agent.channels.CH.capacity = 1000

agent.sources = SRC
agent.sources.SRC.type = avro
agent.sources.SRC.bind = localhost.localdomain
agent.sources.SRC.port = 2222
agent.sources.SRC.channels = CH

agent.sources.SRC.interceptors = i1
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.regex = ^.*(aa).*$
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.serializers = t1
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.serializers.t1.name = A:

agent.sinks = SNK
agent.sinks.SNK.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.SNK.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.SNK.channel = CH
agent.sinks.SNK.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/test/fl1/
```

When i tried Regex Extractor Interceptor with multiplexing channel selector,the events containing "aa" were routed to "/user/cloudera/test/fl1/" and events containing "bb" were routed to "/user/cloudera/test/fl2/" but headers were not appended in this case too. Below is my config file content :

```
agent.channels = CH1 CH2
agent.channels.CH1.type = CHory
agent.channels.CH1.capacity = 100
agent.channels.CH2.type = CHory
agent.channels.CH2.capacity = 100

agent.sources = SRC
agent.sources.SRC.channels = ch1
agent.sources.SRC.type = avro
agent.sources.SRC.bind = localhost.localdomain
agent.sources.SRC.port = 2222

agent.sources.SRC.channels = CH1 CH2
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors = i1



agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.regex = ^.*(aa|bb).*$
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.serializers = t1
agent.sources.SRC.interceptors.i1.serializers.t1.name = type1
agent.sources.SRC.selector.type = multiplexing
agent.sources.SRC.selector.header = type1
agent.sources.SRC.selector.mapping.aa = CH1
agent.sources.SRC.selector.default = CH2

agent.sinks = SNK1 SNK2
agent.sinks.SNK1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.SNK1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.SNK1.channel = CH1
agent.sinks.SNK1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/test/fl1/

agent.sinks.SNK2.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.SNK2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.SNK2.channel = CH2
agent.sinks.SNK2.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/test/fl2/
```

Any help is appreciated.
With Regards

Comment: I'm not sure what your are trying to achieve - but as to your configuration - your mutliplexer example sets a header called type1. If you want to use that in your hdfs sink path specification, you can use the %{type1} notation.

Comment: @Erik I want to append headers to each event 
for example :   If i my incoming event body contains"Hadoop" , i want to append "O:" as a header to that even before storing into hdfs so that my resultant data would look like "O:Hadoop"

Comment: Regexp interceptor only allows you to read properties from your event and copy those values to the specific header. If you want to customize header values, you will have to write your own interceptor.

Comment: @Erik 
What about Static Interceptor ?

Comment: Static interceptor set constant headers without conditions, so this will not help except if you detach your channels with avro sink and avro sources. While you can do that, it seems to be more complicated than writing your own interceptor. If you need help setting up the regex + avro sink/source + static interceptor set up let me know.

Comment: @Erik Thanks Erik. I tried regex + avro sink/source + static interceptor  set up too. I got similar results as my 2nd configuration , which i mentioned in my question. I used different approach using hive to manipulate the data.

PS: If you have any good example for configuring and running flume agents using java APIs , Please post them here.